# How to contour shade two specified contours?

Tags: plotting

I want to have contour shading between two contours specified by two equations like below,

```
ContourPlot[{Sin[x] Sin[y] == 1/2, Sin[x] Sin[y] == 1/3}, 
  {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  ContourShading -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

However, I failed to generate any color between the two contours. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can plot the area using `RegionPlot`.

```
Show[ContourPlot[{Sin[x] Sin[y] == 1/2, Sin[x] Sin[y] == 1/3}, {x, -3,3}, {y, 
-3, 3}], RegionPlot[{Sin[x] Sin[y] < 1/2 && Sin[x] Sin[y]> 1/3}, {x, -3, 3}, 
{y, -3, 3}, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Try specifying the problem as the contours of a single function, rather than as two separate functions.

```
 ContourPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y],
   {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
   Contours -> {1/2, 1/3},
   ContourShading -> {None, Blue},
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How my edit is what the OP wanted.

Comment: Thanks. But if I indeed use two different functions, what I should do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DensityPlot` and `MeshShading` to color between contours using  a color gradient:

```
mesh = {1/4, 2/3};
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Gray, Thick], 
 Mesh -> {mesh}, MeshShading -> {None, Automatic}, PlotPoints -> 300, MaxRecursion -> 5, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"DarkRainbow", {-1, 1}}], ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `RegionFunction` to specify the region between the contours

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, mesh[[1]] <= z <= mesh[[2]]], 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Gray, Thick], 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"DarkRainbow", {-1, 1}}], ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: @Szabolcs, just did. Thank you.